# How to cause open event of jQuery UI tooltip to obey the show.delay property setting

Tags: jquery-ui, settimeout, jquery-ui-tooltip

The open event of the jQuery UI tooltip fires not when the popup opens visibly but as soon as the mouse enters the element. It does not obey the show.delay property setting.  This is documented behavior so I suppose it is not a bug.

So if I have tooltip on adjacent cells of a table, and the user drags the mouse across these cells, the actions in my open and close handlers are taken multiple times -- three, four, five times -- as many times as the number of cells the mouse entered.

What's a good way to exit the open event if the show.delay has not yet transpired?

EDIT: Not knowing how much time has elapsed on the delay.show, I've had to choose an arbitrary duration for the setTimeout, and track whether a class-switch is in progress using a flag:

```
     <snip> ...
     show: {
        delay: 666
     },

    open: function (event, ui) {
            if (me.changingClass) return;           
            me.changingClass = true;
            $("td.baz").switchClass("foo", "bar");

    },
    close: function (event, ui, dupids) {
        $("td.baz").switchClass("bar", "foo");           
        setTimeout(function () { me.changingClass = false; }, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far? I would guess a timeout would do it, but I can't say for sure without seeing what you're working with.

Comment: Can you add enough code to replicate your issue?

Comment: All you have to do to replicate it is to attach the tooltip to the TDs  of a table. open and close fire immediately on mouse enter and mouse leave, not after the show.delay threshold has been reached. So if the user drags the mouse (quickly) across several adjacent cells of a table, entering the cell fires the open event and leaving the cell fires the close event, so if the mouse touched three cells while being moved, those events would each fire three times.

Comment: Can you throw it in a fiddle? I'm not sure how you're achieving the show delay.

Comment: See edit; it is a property of the tooltip configuration object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may do the trick, if I understand what you're after:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/87hkb/2/)**

```
var timer;
$('td').tooltip({
    show: {
        delay: 2000 //number of milliseconds to wait
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var xthis = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $(xthis).siblings().switchClass("bar", "foo");
        }, 2000); // number of milliseconds to wait
    },
    close: function (event, ui, dupids) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).siblings().switchClass("foo", "bar");
    }
});
```